# Lock a Field Instance

Tags: entities

Is there a way to lock a field instance?

I want to prevent users from editing or deleting a given instance, but allow the field to be customizable elsewhere by the user.  If I lock the field, it will do the former, but prevent the latter.

According to [this Field API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7), fields can be locked by setting `locked = TRUE` in the field definition, but there is no corresponding `locked` key for the instance definition.

I experimented by adding `locked = TRUE` to my field instance definition, and while that removed the edit and delete links from the bundle types view, I can still edit and delete by visiting the appropriate url.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a [snippet from dropbucket](http://dropbucket.org/node/901) to lock and unlock fields. I used the snippet in the devel execute php window but it could certainly be coded into a function instead:

```
/*
# You can use Devel Module to unlock/lock a existing field where you would otherwise get an error like "The field xxxx is locked and cannot be edited."
# Change the 'xxx' on line 1 with the machine readable name of your field.
*/
$field_name = 'xxx';
$field = field_read_field($field_name);
$field['locked'] = 1; //change this to 0 to unlock a field
field_update_field($field);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Instill devel module Enable the devel module either by drush en or from admin/build/modules.
```

It will generate several blocks and look for the one named ‘Execute PHP’ enable it by setting it to a preferred region .
 Write the code you want to check on the text area for example and then press execute to see the result.

so here we will use this code

```
$field_name = 'field_name';
$field = field_read_field($field_name);
$field['locked'] = 0; // 0: unlock; 1: lock.
field_update_field($field);
```

note: 
this line

```
$field_name = 'field_name';
```

you have to add your filed name for example like this

```
$field_name = commerce_price;
```

if you got any error such as displayed as messages

```
Notice: Undefined index”
```

or

```
“Notice: Undefined variable”
```

and your logs will grow insanely…

the solution is to add in your settings.php the line

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');
```